# How can a newsletter subscriber be deleted if not verified within 1 month?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have tried the following in an attempt to automatically remove "dead" emails that have not completed the signup process for my newsletter.

Newsletter Controller:

```
def destroy
  Newsletter.find(params[:id]).destroy
  flash[:success] = "You have been unsubscribed from the mailing list. Please, let us know why you left!"
  redirect_to contact_path
  if Newsletter.verified == false && Newsletter.created_at > 1.hour
    Newsletter.find(params[:id]).destroy
  end
end
```

This has 1.hour for testing purposes but would normally have 1 month or maybe 2 weeks:

```
if Newsletter.verified == false && Newsletter.created_at > 1.hour
  Newsletter.find(params[:id]).destroy
end
```

Is this supposed to be in a different method?

Is it supposed to be in my Model?

I'm not sure if this is even the correct way to handle this.

Comment: I find the naming confusing. Is `Newsletter` a newsletter or a subscriber?

Comment: "Is this supposed to be in a different method" - yes, pruning old records is normally in some kind of periodic background job. For example, a rake task called by crond (with help of `whenever` gem, for example). Or a sidekiq job (with something like sidekiq_scheduler)

Comment: Start with this: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Oh, I wasn't sure it had to be different. I've only managed to set up `Newsletter` to be used for signing up, which populates a table with subscribers.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I'm using Sendgrid but would I still need to make an MVC for sending those out? Kind of like making a blog post but it being a newsletter?

Comment: Not sure about sending out, but you'll likely need a controller for tracking signups from your newsletter (which is the whole point, isn't it?) Maybe can be done with customizing devise' signup controller (if you're using devise)

Comment: Does your application already use some kind of background job processing? Cron jobs, Sidekiq, ActiveJob?

Comment: @spickermann no, I was hoping to just DIY it but if I need a gem then it's fine. I don't use Devise either.

Comment: That `NewsletterController#destroy` method will only be called when one specific subscriber wants to unsubscribe. But I guess you want to clean up your database on a regular base without having to load a specific webpage. Therefore I was asking how and when you want to trigger that cleanup method. Or I am wrong and you are fine with doing that un-regularly as a side effect of another method or by calling a specific admin route?

Comment: @spickermann You're correct, I want to delete any subscriber that hasn't verified their email within 1 month as I figure they won't after that point anyway and I would just have a dead email in my DB. It doesn't have to be in the destroy method, it's just what I've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a class method to our `Newsletter` class:

```
# in app/models/newsletter.rb
def self.remove_outdated
  where(verified: false).where('created_at < ?', 1.hour.ago).destroy_all
end
```

Then call that method from somewhere in our application – perhaps from an admin controller method, from a regular CRON task via `rails runner` or from a scheduled background job:

```
Newsletter.remove_outdated
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but I can't make sense of `'created_at < ?', 1.hour.ago`.

Comment: `'created_at < ?', 1.hour.ago` finds all records which were created more than 1 hour ago. Read is as the date of creation is smaller than the timestamp one hour ago.